# Xamarin Studio doesn't launch IOS SImulator

Tags: xamarin, ios-simulator

Can't open IOS7 Simulator for Xamarin

> Xamarin Studio dont launch the IOS Simulator

Hi, I have a problem running the IOS Simulator, I have installed Xcode6-Beta6 on my mac and IOS7.1 & IOS8 Simulator. When I open my .xib file Xcode6-Beta6 is opened and I set in the "Interface Builder Document" builds for IOS 7.1 and I save the file, but when i run my app from Xamarin Studio the IOS Simulator does not open and i have no errors or warnings , What I have to do? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Xamarin fixed it for me.